# How can I print the assertion with a value even if it get passed in Postman Api Testing

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase, postman-native-app, postman-mocks

As a user, while executing the test cases created for the API Request, I'm expecting that it must show the value of the assertion even if the test cases pass.

For Example:

```
pm.test("User ID Should Exist", ()=>{

    value = bodyData.data.currentUser.id

    pm.expect(value).to.exist

    pm.environment.set("userID", value) 
})
```

When I run it, so it displays:

**PASS - User ID Should Exist**

How can I print the value of the User Id, even if the case passes on the test result section/tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
value = bodyData.data.currentUser.id

pm.test("User ID '" + value + "' should Exist", ()=>{

    pm.expect(value).to.exist

    pm.environment.set("userID", value) 
})
```